# variables in $_GET superglobal

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have this page of code. It handles my content. It works great:

```
<?PHP
    $page = $_GET["page"];
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $filename = $page . '.php';
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            include $filename;
        } else {
            echo "deze pagina bestaat niet";
        }
    } else {
        include 'user.php';
    }
 ?>
```

Now i want to go a step further and include a variable after the ?page=something.php
If i put &ID=24 after it is says that the page does not exist. for instance:

```
echo "<a href='?page=something.php&ID=" .$row['ID'] . "'>something</a>"
```

I understand why it doesn't work but i don't see how to make it work.

Comment: sidenote: put `$page = $_GET["page"];` inside the `if(isset) ...`

Comment: **You should stop what you're doing with this code**, you're creating vulnerabilities in your system. One of them is [**`LFI`**](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion). If you're going to do it this way you should be using a whitelist to match against and even then you'll still have issues in your code.

Comment: I'm learning php. I'm a beginner. I use sessions to access this page so maybe i'm less vulnerable. My site is for learning practices.

Comment: @user3547914 No its still vulnerable. Sessions aren't going to stop somebody trying to access your `.htpasswd` files or any other core files.

Comment: @Darren i changed this $page = str_replace('../', '', $_GET['page']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ".php" in this code :

```
echo "<a href='?page=something.php&ID=" .$row['ID'] . "'>something</a>"
```

Because when you check file to include, you already add extension :

```
$filename = $page . '.php';
```

Comment: It should works fine now. Does the issue still exists even after trying the above solution?

Comment: It works! I had to add the extension .php in the menu file. This helps me.